# Opening a binary stream (such as a PDF) in the browser

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, web

So, currently I have successfully retrieved the binary data from an URL (in most cases this is a PDF). I have done this simply using:

```
byte[] binaryData = myWebClient.DownloadData(product.Url);
```

Now I want to display a clickable link/button to the user in which they can open this PDF in the browser.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a controller with an action and return the PDF

```
public class PDFDownloadController : Controller 
{
     public ActionResult Download() {  
         using (var myWebClient = new WebClient()) 
         {
            var product = .... // Init product
            byte[] binaryData = myWebClient.DownloadData(product.Url);
            return File(binaryData, "application/pdf");
         }
     }
}
```

Add an html anchor with URL `http://yourwebsite/PDFDownload/Download`

Comment: Cheers! Works great! :)